# Finding multiple brackets through loop

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code which I am using to separate data, when '('bracket has found, but I want to do it for multiple brackets occurs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "A+(B*C)*D";
    string a=getBetween(str, "(", ")");
    str = str.Replace(a, "()");
    MessageBox.Show("string is=" + a);
    MessageBox.Show("string is=" + str);
}

}
public string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
   int Start, End;
   if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
   {
       Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
       End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
       return "(" +strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start)+")";
   }
   else
   {
      return "";

   }
```

I want to do it for multiple brakcets
like `string="A+(B+(C*D))"`

Comment: You can use stack data structure ! Just hint !

Comment: So, if the source string is `"A+(B+(C*D))"`, what would you like the method to return?

Comment: I want to capture all the data inside the brackets as an another string,likewise I want to store all innerloop strings as list of strings.

Comment: for example, source string:A+(B+C) string 1=B+C, source string=A+()

Comment: So your method can't just return a string, it should return a collection of strings...

Comment: You should add a set of example input and expected output for your function.

Comment: yes ,like wise I need my source string should be change each time I found the bracket,like source input:A+(B+(C*D)),String1=B+(C*D)Then there exist of '(' in string1 then I process string1 using function,then my string2 is=B+()

Comment: This can probably be done with a regular expression, but it's also a good candidate for a recursive function. Just throwing you some ideas here.

Comment: could anyone help me regarding this, I am not getting how to explore it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will extract all the strings inside brackets.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Extract(string sourceStr, string startStr, string endStr)
{
    var startIndices = IndexOfAll(sourceStr, startStr).ToArray();
    var endIndices = IndexOfAll(sourceStr, endStr).ToArray();
    if(startIndices.Length != endIndices.Length)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Missmatch");

    for (int i = 0; i < startIndices.Length; i++)
    {
        var start = startIndices[i];
        var end = endIndices[endIndices.Length - 1 - i];
        yield return sourceStr.Substring(start, end - start + 1);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<int> IndexOfAll(string source, string subString)
{
    return Regex.Matches(source, Regex.Escape(subString)).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Index);
}
```

So `A+(B+(C*D))` would return two strings `(B+(C*D))` and `(C*D)`

Comment: Hi!! this code has helped me a lot, but now I am facing an another issue, how will it work if my input having a multiple series brackets like:A*(B+(C*(D+E)*F)*G)*(H*F*D)+(D+Q)